# valgrind complains: Invalid write of size 8, On malloc

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

I am not able to figure out, why I see this error while running Valgrind.

```
struct char_ctx {
    int  arr_size;
    char **char_array;
};

void char_compile() {

    struct char_ctx *ctx  = malloc(sizeof(struct char_ctx*));
    ctx->char_array = malloc((100) * sizeof(char *)); // I see error with this.
    char **y = malloc((100) * sizeof(char *)); // I dont see error with this.

    ctx->arr_size  = 100;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    
    char_compile();
    return 0;
}
```

**Valgrind output**

```
==30585== Invalid write of size 8
==30585==    at 0x108671: char_compile (temp.c:54)
==30585==    by 0x1086A8: main (temp.c:63)
==30585==  Address 0x522f048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==30585==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30585==    by 0x10865B: char_compile (temp.c:53)
==30585==    by 0x1086A8: main (temp.c:63)
```

The code executes properly.
I see the error on `ctx->char_array`, but when I use `char **y`, I don't see the error.

Comment: `struct char_ctx *ctx  = malloc(sizeof(struct char_ctx));` or better `struct char_ctx *ctx  = malloc(sizeof(*ctx))`;

Comment: Perfect, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
struct char_ctx *ctx  = malloc(sizeof(struct char_ctx*));
```

You're only allocating space for a pointer to `struct char_ctx`, not a `struct char_ctx`.  Because of this, a write to `ctx->char_array` writes past the end of allocated memory.

You instead want:

```
struct char_ctx *ctx  = malloc(sizeof(struct char_ctx));
```

Or better yet:

```
struct char_ctx *ctx  = malloc(sizeof *ctx);
```